# Why is the data being change outside directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can not figure out why the data being change outside the directive in `external div`, I think it should be same as controller behavior because the `external Div` did not wrap in `directive` and `controller`, so should still be nothing instead of being evaluate, please help figure out why, thanks.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TuzpaWqO1hugdmPIO5qk?p=preview)

```js
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective', function() {
      return {
        link: function(scope) {
          scope.dataFormDirective = "directiveData";
        }
      }
    })
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.data = "controllerData";
    })
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div>external div</div>
  <div>controllerData: {{data}}</div>
  <div>dataFormDirective: {{dataFormDirective}}</div>
  </br>

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    myCtrl
    <div>controllerData : {{data}}</div>
    <div>dataFormDirective:{{dataFormDirective}}</div>
  </div>
  </br>

  <div my-directive>myDirective {{dataFormDirective}}</div>

</body>
```

Comment: I believe this is because your directive is sharing it's parent scope, you would need a directive option of `scope: true,` or something

Comment: @SmokeyPHP you are right, I add the scope:true, and it works normally, thank you! Wish I could mark you as answer, by the way, is this directive using the $rootscope? since there is no controller above it.

Comment: I believe it will, yes, I've always created containing scopes to avoid using the root scope, but technically with the way it works, I imagine the values would indeed be on `$rootScope` - easily tested by injecting it into your directive and doing `console.log('root data:', $rootScope.data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By @SmokeyPHP Comment, add `scope:true` will resolve the issue.

This is because the directive will share the parent scope but controller, in my example, **the directive scope will be the $rootscope since there is no controller wrap it**.

```js
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .directive('myDirective',function() {
      return {
        scope:true,
        link: function(scope) {
              scope.dataFormDirective = "directiveData";
        }
      }
    })
    .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = "controllerData";
    })
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div>external div</div>
  <div>data: {{data}}</div>
  <div>dataFormDirective: {{dataFormDirective}}</div>
  </br>

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    myCtrl
    <div>data : {{data}}</div>
    <div>dataFormDirective:{{dataFormDirective}}</div>
  </div>
  </br>

  <div my-directive>myDirective {{dataFormDirective}}</div>

</body>
```